# How can I move a directory in a Git repo for all commits?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Let's say I have a repo that includes this directory structure:

```
repo/
  blog/
    _posts/
      some-post.html
  another-file.txt
```

I want to move `_posts` to the top level of the repo, so the structure will look like this:

```
repo/
  _posts/
    some-post.html
  another-file.txt
```

This is simple enough with `git mv`, but I want to make the history look as though `_posts` *always* existed at the root of the repo, and I want to be able to get the entire history of `some-post.html` via `git log -- _posts/some-post.html`. I imagine I can use some magic with `git filter-branch` to accomplish this, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use the subdirectory filter to achieve this

```
 $ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter blog/ -- --all
```

**EDIT 1:** If you don't want to effectively make `_posts` the root, use a tree-filter instead:

```
 $ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv blog/_posts .' HEAD
```

**EDIT 2:** If `blog/_posts` did not exist in some of the commits, the above will fail. Use this instead:

```
 $ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test -d blog/_posts && mv blog/_posts . || echo "Nothing to do"' HEAD
```

Comment: It's also *much* faster to use `--index-filter`, since it doesn't have to check out the tree.

Comment: Yeah index-filter is faster, but it won't work because the commands shown do _not_ affect the index. You need to do index manipulations only if you want to use index-filter (e.g. `git rm --cached` instead of `rm`)

Comment: Can I keep tags too? It looks like they are gone in my case.

Comment: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git read-tree --prefix=/ $GIT_COMMIT:_posts; git rm -r --cached _posts' -- --all`.  Add `--tag-name-filter cat` if your tags aren't signed and you want to move them/invalidate the old ones.

Comment: For those that are here just for copy-paste: remember to `git push --force --all` for all the branches. Otherwise you can end up with funny situations.

Comment: No need to make the last command so complicated.

To move existing folder somewhere else regardless if it exists in all commits, just run
`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git mv -k blog/_posts .'`

Index filter will not work in that case, as you are modifying the tree objects as well (and you need to have them checked-out), not just the index. The `-k` switch will take care of the "nonexistent" files in some commits.

Answer (score 40):

While Ramkumar's answer is very helpful and worthwile, it will not work in many situations.
For example, when you want to move a directory with other subdirectories to a new location.

For this, the man page contains the perfect command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
  'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&NEWSUBDIR/-" |
   GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
   git update-index --index-info &&
   mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

Just replace NEWSUBDIR with your desired new directory.
You can also use nested dirs like dir1/dir2/dir3/-"

Comment: And since it's not immediately obvious from looking at that command or the resulting errors, the \t doesn't work on os x's version of sed.  There's lots of ways around that, but perhaps the quickest is to delete the \t and replace it with a literal tab by typing ctrl-v, <tab>.

Comment: How do you specify the original folder, or does this just move the entire branch? When I try to run this from a folder I'd like to move I get `You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree`

Comment: What does the `sed` command do? I'm trying this on Windows and need an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! @Lucius, the sed command is much more clear if you replace the "&" with another \t and the "-"s with an @.

Comment: Brilliant. But yes the sed is confusing so try the second line alone to test it. I.e. to remove unnecessary top level directories I did a simple `git ls-files -s | sed "s-\tdir1/dir2/dir3/-\t-"`

Comment: I tried so many answers on the internet, this is the only one working - thx a lot!

Comment: If you're filtering a commit that effectively deletes all files you end up with `git update-index` not creating the file "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" and thus the mv command fails. I ended up with

    `test -f \$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new && mv \$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \$GIT_INDEX_FILE || touch \$GIT_INDEX_FILE`

inside the filter-branch script.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud  I get the error of index.new': No such file or directory, as this git repository was a result of an svn-migration, there is no initial commit. Could you share your command, or is it just insert that into the filter, with no quotations?

Comment: @Jägermeister - just replace the "mv" command in theduke's example with the "test && mv || touch" combination from my comment.

Comment: Something about using `-` as a separator confused my sed, so I had to change that like so: `sed "s:\t\"*:&NEWSUBDIR/:"`.

Comment: As noted, BSD/macos sed does not support `\t`, and the pattern fails on paths with hyphens in their name -- so I wrote a cross platform solution that uses awk;

`git ls-files -s | awk '{ sub(/\t/, "\tsubdir/"); print}' `

full usage: set DEST to desired subdir

`DEST="subdir/path/" git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | awk -v prefix="$DEST/" "{ sub(/\t/, \"\t\" prefix); print}" GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD`

Comment: @briceburg The `mv` is missing between `&&` and `"$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new"`. Other than that, it works perfectly!

Comment: Fails with the following error Rewrite 7576b38152b393793b1c9ec3df0ff86685f95236 (1/8246) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    mv: cannot stat '/tmp/controller/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
index filter failed: git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&opendaylight/blueprint/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"

Comment: @askb: You can skip bad commits with appending `; /bin/true`. See [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677910/4566599).

Comment: For those Windows users who stumbled on this answers like me and wonder how to make it work on Windows: consider using WSLS and run the command from linux. Just make sure that your repository is checked out with AutoCRLF to false or else the git command in linux is going to think all files have changes and will block the execution.

Comment: Running under Cygwin on Windows, the above didn't work. Eventually, my issue was that my subdir contains dashes (e.g. "sect-03"), which is the separator used in the `sed` section. Replacing `sed "s-\t\"*-&sect-03/-"` with `sed "s/\t\"*/&sect-03\//"` did the trick.

Comment: I also ran into a problem with the `-` being used as the sed separator when I was trying to move a directory that had a hyphen in the name. It took me forever to realize what was going on. I'm guessing they went away from the usual sed `/` separator because that's common to see that character used in paths. It might be smarter to use an even less commonly used character such as `^` instead:

`sed "s^\t\"*^&NEWSUBDIR/^"`

Answer (score 4):

Created a generic script for arbitrary moves/renames: https://gist.github.com/xkr47/f766f4082112c086af63ef8d378c4304

Examples:

```
git filter-mv 's!^!subdir/!'
```

➜ moves all files to a subdirectory "subdir/" in all commits of the current branch

```
git filter-mv 's!^foo/bar.txt$!foo/barbar.txt!'
```

➜ renames foo/bar.txt to foo/barbar.txt in all commits of the current branch

Answer (score 2):

git `filter-branch` is discouraged. You can use git `filter-repo` is much more convenient:

```
git filter-repo --path-rename blog/_posts:_posts
```

See [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

Also note that installation somehow is [broken](https://superuser.com/questions/1563034/how-do-you-install-git-filter-repo), and you have to install from pip and add `git-filter-repo` to `$PATH`