# How to remove local git history after a commit?

Tags: git, versioning, history

I would like to switch from Dropbox to the open source Sparkleshare. It uses git for the syncing and versioning. If say I had a 1GB file I deleted in my folder, it stays within the history of the local .git folder. But I would like to have this kind of heavy data on the server and not the client. 
How can I commit my repository and delete the local one with git?
Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152550/moving-a-git-directory

Answer (score 30):

#### Solution removing the history

1. `git fetch --depth=1` to prune the old commits. This makes the old commits and their objects unreachable.
2. `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`. To expire all old commits and their objects
3. `git gc --aggressive --prune=all` to remove the old objects

#### Specific solution just to remove the large file in the local history

- GitHub offer's [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/), which stores large files always on the server and fetches them only on checkouts. Very easy to setup and use - in case your repository is on GitHub, bitbucket, or gitlab.
- [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) - allows storing big files anywhere

Discussion: [How do Git LFS and git-annex differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39337586/873282)

Answer (score 3):

Based on koppor's answer, I created this single line bash command to clear the local git history from all repositories which are in the same base folder:

```sh
for d in */; do echo $d && cd "$d" && git fetch --depth=1 && git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all && git gc --aggressive --prune=all; cd ..; done
```

Note: you can replace `*/` by any specific folder criteria if you wish, such as `*mobile*/` .

Windows cmd version (untested):

```
FOR /D %d IN (*) DO (echo $d && cd "$d" && git fetch --depth=1 && git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all && git gc --aggressive --prune=all & cd ..)
```

This has saved me a few gigabytes !

Answer (score 0):

Add the below commands in cmd or sh file and should help in clearing the history
git fetch --depth=1 to prune the old commits. This makes the old commits and their objects unreachable.
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all. To expire all old commits and their objects
git gc --aggressive --prune=all to remove the old objects