# bfg or filter-branch to correct history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, bfg-repo-cleaner

I found this answer over here:
[Duplicate commits after filter-branch to move root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250289/duplicate-commits-after-filter-branch-to-move-root-directory)

Which is probably what I should have done originally. I had a repo like:

```
./.git
./project/something
./project/lots_of_stuff/
```

I wanted "project/" to be the root of my project. I forget exactly what I did to end up with "project/" as the root. So I have a commit that's like

```
-- project/something
-- ... lots of stuff ...

++ something
++ ... lots of stuff ...

commit message: "big move"
```

Technically, I have a full history, but "big move" messed it up so for example if I do `git log something` I get:

```
abcdef1234
"big move"

fff1234faa
"changes since the big move"
```

But obviously I have changes before the big move. Is it possible to filter-branch or bfg my way out of this?

Comment: Have you tried `git log --follow something`?

Comment: You may also find [this aswer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15135004/3290797) useful.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like `--follow` should be adequate. Looks like this may be a situation where git is not magic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make github follow directory history after renames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646174/how-to-make-github-follow-directory-history-after-renames)