# git moving file while keeping history

Tags: git

we are using git at work.
we want to move a directory called "Workflows" from under
Source/Workflows

to a new location
Source/Sites/CompanySite/Workflows

my colleague did a copy of that directory to the new location "Source/Sites/CompanySite/Workflows" and checked-in before doing a "git mv" command or even doing a move.

So, we have new copies of the files in that location with no history.

But because we want to just move files keeping their history, so I deleted the new copy and tried to do "git mv" to move the source files, while keeping the history.
And I know that git will recognize that we are renaming even without "git mv"

But because my colleague copy has already a history there (which is an empty one), so even when I delete it it keep that "new history".

Then no matter what I do, I am not able to move those files with their "original history".

because  it always keeping the "new history" that was there.

I hope my question is clear

How can I move these files keeping their history.
maybe "purging" that old copy????

Comment: How far back in the history did your co-worker do this and how big is the team (IE, how practical is rebasing to throw away your co-worker's commit and try again)?

Comment: I recommend the solution posted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13590229/1579915.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git mv` doesn't actually ensure that Git will see it as a move; it may still treat it as a delete + addition, anyway. Git infers moves, but doesn't record them.

If you want the history, try passing the `--follow` flag to `git log`—it may be able to recognize the connection to the original and show the history for it.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your requirements: there is a possibility to use [git-filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

this allows you to apply a shellscript on every commit like: `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD`

be aware though that it will create new commit-ids for each commit. See also [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142419/how-can-i-move-a-directory-in-a-git-repo-for-all-commits) on moving files with filter-tree.