# git, sure-fire way to move/rename files while keeping the history

Tags: git, rename, move

I know there are "lots" of existing questions that looks similar, so let me summarize them before asking mine.

- The answer to [Is it possible to move/rename files in git and maintain their history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history) is, "it is not possible".
- The conclusion for [git moving file while keeping history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147248/git-moving-file-while-keeping-history) is, Git *may* see it as a move, or it *may still* treat it as a delete + addition.

The answer to the first one, I don't agree, because I've done that before.  The answer to the second one is the reason why I'm asking this question. I.e.,

I found I am doing `git mv` all the times, but sometime it is treated as move/rename, and sometime it is treated as delete + addition. Thus, I want to know how I can make it always a move/rename?

Take [this one](https://github.com/suntong/easygen/commit/b387613a1a233cc97462a77c86fcaef105f5b8dc) as an example, at the bottom, we can see several move/rename cases, like `easygenapi/tf-varcaser.go → tf-varcaser.go`. Note that such moves are *across/between the folders*! I.e., I *did* it!

But there are many other cases `git mv` were treated as delete + addition, showing in the exactly same change log. Again, I am doing `git mv` all the times. Why `git` behave differently?

Is there any *sure-fire* way to move/rename git files while keeping the history?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

tl;dr; no

Longer version:
In my experience, git is very good at detecting the move/rename as long as the file is unmodified. Git uses heuristics to attempt and locate the move. It can be fooled by having several files that are too similar, or if the file has been modified during the move, causing it to be too dissimilar from its original.

The best way I have found to do this is to do multi-stage commits, separating all of your moves into one commit, followed by the changes in another. For example...

```
git mv foo.txt bar.txt
git commit

... modify bar.txt ...

git add bar.txt
git commit
```

It will not guarantee your move is detected correctly, as it can still get confused when there are multiple candidates. However it has worked very well for me and catches the majority of cases.

Comment: Thanks. Much helpful than the other answer which states, *"Git doesn't track renames. Period."*, which got five vote while this one get none. OK. I'll make sure to play that *multi-stage commits* trick from now on and see.

Comment: To be fair, the other answer is far more informative :) I upvoted it myself. I added this answer because I felt it was too abstract and did not directly answer your question.

Comment: I've just tried this, and despite git showing the change as a rename during commit, I *still* lost all my change history for the file!

Comment: @AnotherHowie Git doesn't show this by default. You can track the history using the `--follow` option (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---follow).

Comment: To track full history of such moved file use `git log -p --follow bar.txt`.

Comment: To be fair a commit should be focussed on one thing, so changing and renaming would be better as two commits anyway.

Answer (score 20):

Git doesn't track renames. Period. It also doesn't track adds. Or deletes. Or diffs. Or patches. Or moves. Or any sort of change, really.

Git is snapshot-based. Every commit records a snapshot of the entire project. That's it. *How* that snapshot came to be, Git neither knows nor cares.

Diffs, patches, adds, deletes, moves, renames, etc. are shown by various visualization tools, which infer them after the fact using heuristics (which is another way of saying "guessing"). Sometimes, they may guess correctly what you did, and sometimes they don't. It doesn't matter, though, because it's only visualization, it's not part of the history in any way, shape, or form.

Most tools use some form of similarity metric, and infer that a rename occurred if two files have a similarity greater than some threshold. In some tools, this threshold is configurable. In some tools, even the algorithm is configurable. (A slightly related example: `git diff` allows you to choose between different algorithms for inferring differences *within* files.)

Since Git doesn't record changes, it is possible to add new changes in later versions of the visualization tools which can infer those changes from older commits which were recorded before the new tools which understand new kinds of changes were even written. Imagine, for example, a tool which understands the syntax and semantics of the programming language you are using. It could visualize a certain commit not as a whole bunch of files each having a couple of lines changed, but as a single change which renames a subroutine and updates each callsite (i.e. the *Rename Method Refactoring*).

Renames are actually a good example of this. The rename detection heuristics and similarity metrics used by `git log --follow`, for example, were improved multiple times. IIRC, in the beginning, renames weren't inferred at all, that capability was added later. This would simply not have been possible, if Git recorded changes instead of snapshots.

Comment: In this sense, Git isn't so much a "stupid content tracker" as it is a "stupid content."