# Git individual file history lost with git subtree

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm merging 2 git repositores (old1 & old2) into 1 (new1). My requirements are to merge all branches & to keep the git commit history. First one I can achieve but I'm struggling with the commit history.

This is the command I execute to merge the old1 repo in a sub folder of the new1: `git subtree add -P old1 https://github.com/example/old1.git master`

Output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`:

```
*   ad4fcb6 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add 'komed-connector/' from commit '50b42475113c295c66c4050b3b0f119a6ebff62b'
|\  
| * 50b4247 Updated komed-shared
| *   1a5435a Merge branch 'master' into openshift_build
| |\  
| | *   8aa90aa Merge branch 'r/3.4'
| | |\  
| | | * a6cea77 updated shared
| | * | a40c782 Updated komed-shared
...
```

So far so good: git commit history is kept. But if I'm inspecting the git commits of a single file in the new sub folder it doesn't show all commits:
[image]

**How can I merge 2 repos into 1 and keep the individual file git commit history?** So when running `gitk old1/Dockerfile` git shows me all commits that happened on the old repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that Git does not have the concept of "individual file commit history". Tracking of the fact that old1/Dockerfile is related to some other file in some different location is left to heuristics in visual and command line tools (or lack thereof). More discussion of this can be found in this question: [git, sure-fire way to move/rename files while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618507/git-sure-fire-way-to-move-rename-files-while-keeping-the-history?rq=1)

From the practical standpoint, I would try rewriting the "old" repo history as if it entirely occured in the `oldreporoot/old1` folder. Then this repo can be merged cleanly into the new repo, and your visual/command line tools should behave accordingly, as files are not renamed/moved.

`git filter-branch --tree-filter` should help get this done, as described in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History